# How do I store class variables in memory?

Tags: memory, screeps

I read a few other questions here about it but I'm just not getting it.

I have some variables that change through the course of execution so I understand that they need to go in memory.

```
var populationManager = {

    init: function(){
        Memory.PopulationManager = {};
        Memory.PopulationManager.nHarvesters = 0;
        Memory.PopulationManager.nUpgraders = 0;
        Memory.PopulationManager.nBuilders = 0;

        Memory.PopulationManager.harvesterNameNum = 0;
        Memory.PopulationManager.upgraderNameNum = 0;
        Memory.PopulationManager.builderNameNum = 0;
    },

    demographics: function(){
         if( ! Memory.PopulationManager.nHarvesters )
             this.init(); //not initialized yet
```

But it is telling me it `cannot read property nHarvesters of undefined`.

How do I make my own screeps Memory objects and use them?

Comment: What output do you get it you do a JSON.Stringify(Memory.PopulationManager) in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking over your code I found that the issue is that you are checking for a property of an object that doesn't exist and want you should be doing is checking if the actual object exists.

Change

`if( ! Memory.PopulationManager.nHarvesters )`

to

`if( ! Memory.PopulationManager )`

and that will do what you need it to.